# Which class of axis2-1.6.2.jar supports http doGet and doPost operations?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I have included axis2-1.6.2.jar in my web app project. But when I try to login, I get the error that: This URL does not support doGet and doPost. The coding of servlet is correct. So, I doubt that this is a problem with a jar file. Kindly tell me that which jar file should I include with axis2-1.6.2.jar in order to support the doGet and doPost method. Any help would be appreciated. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code, there are three classes that implement `doGet` and `doPost` methods in the Axis2 codebase.  Two of them are in samples, so you must be looking for this one:

- `org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet`

That can be found in `axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar` but it could be in the JAR file you are using as well.  (It looks like an omnibus JAR).

You can `jar tvf <jar-file-name>` to check what it in a JAR file.